# ::after css pseudo element to cover element and all child elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I want to cover the element with the `::after` pseudo element, but when I add child elements div element, it pushes the `::after` down.

I want to keep the inline block display of the child element. When the user hovers, the transition shows the child element under the `::after` element.

Works with no child elements but when I add the text in `.subsect-text` pushes pseudo element down.

```css
[class^="sect__"] {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 20vh;
    /* background: linear-gradient(to right, var(--light-purple), var(--dark-purple) 50%, var(--dark-purple) 75%); */
}

[class^='container__subsect']{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: calc(100%/3);

}

[class^='container__subsect']::after{
    font-size: 4rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    
}

.container__subsect-1::after{
    content: "Networking";
}

.container__subsect-2::after{
    content: "JavaScript";
}

.container__subsect-3::after{
    content: "Endpoint Management";
}


[class^='container__subsect']:hover::after{
    height: 0%;
    content: "";
}

.subsect-text {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 2rem;
    display: inline;
    /* position: absolute; */
}
```

```html
<section class="sect__1">
    <div class="container__subsect-1">
        <div class="subsect-text">
            Networking with meraki is a way of using cloud-based technology to manage and monitor networks of devices, such as routers, switches, cameras, and access points. Meraki provides a dashboard that allows users to configure, troubleshoot, and secure their networks from anywhere.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container__subsect-2">
        <div class="subsect-text">
            Javascript is a programming language that runs in web browsers and enables dynamic and interactive web pages. Javascript can also be used for server-side development, mobile applications, desktop applications, and game development. Javascript is one of the most popular and widely used languages in the world.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container__subsect-3">
        <div class="subsect-text">
            Endpoint management is the process of securing and maintaining the devices that connect to a network, such as laptops, smartphones, tablets, and printers. Endpoint management involves installing software updates, enforcing security policies, detecting and resolving threats, and providing remote support.
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: "*I want to cover the element*" - which one? You have several to choose from.

Comment: The elements with the ::after pseudo element being applied. [class^='container__subsect']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is as follows, with explanatory comments in the code:

```css
/*
  a simple reset to remove all browser default padding and margins,
  and setting the box-sizing algorithm to border-box, which includes
  border-widths and padding in the assigned size:
*/

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* unchanged: */

section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 20vh;
}

.container__subsect {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  /* rather than calculating a width, I set the flex-basis
     (the size of the element on the inline-axis) to be
     30% of its parent; this allows for some spacing between
     adjacent elements and also to give an appromately same
     size to the siblings):
  */
  flex-basis: 30%;
  /*
    a personal preference to move the content away from the
    border, to give a slightly less-cramped visual layout:
  */
  padding: 0.5rem;
  /*
    in order to ensure that the pseudo-element can be positioned
    relative to its parent:
  */
  position: relative;
}

.container__subsect::after {
  /*
     setting a partially transparent background-color, in order
     to see that there's content behind the titles; obviously
     adjust if you don't want that translucency:
  */
  background-color: #fff6;
  /*
     displaying the value of the data-title attribute as the
     content:
  */
  content: attr(data-title);
  /*
     adding a small blur with the backdrop-filter property,
     and the CSS blur() function; again: remove if this isn't
     desired:
  */
  backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
  font-size: 2rem;
  /*
    using the inset property to set the top, right, bottom and
    left positions with one value (all to 0):
  */
  inset: 0;
  /*
    preventing the pseudo-element being visible outside of the
    it's parent element:
  */
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  transition: inset 0.4s ease-in;
}

.container__subsect:hover::after {
  /*
    I used calc() to show how it could be used to keep the
    "title" visible if you wished to do so, this is
    unfortunately a magic number so I'm not entirely keen
    on the idea; if you want the "title" to slide entirely
    out of view, then use the following instead:
      inset: 100% 0 0 0;
  */
  inset: calc(100% - 4rem) 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="sect__1">
  <!--
    below I've made two changes (these aren't required, but does simplify things):
      1. added a "container__subject" class, so that *all* of these elements
         can be selected with one selector that works more efficiently (though
         this is a micro-optimisation) than using the attribute-starts-with
         selector, and should run better on older/slower hardware; also it
         allows you to add, insert, prepend or append new classes without
         having to worry about the selector, and
      2. I've added the "data-title" attribute, setting its value to be equal
         to the relevant subject of the descendant .subsect-text element
  -->
  <div class="container__subsect container__subsect-1" data-title="Networking">
    <div class="subsect-text">
      Networking with Meraki is a way of using cloud-based technology to manage and monitor networks of devices, such as routers, switches, cameras, and access points. Meraki provides a dashboard that allows users to configure, troubleshoot, and secure their networks from anywhere.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container__subsect container__subsect-2" data-title="JavaScript">
    <div class="subsect-text">
      JavaScript is a programming language that runs in web browsers and enables dynamic and interactive web pages. JavaScript can also be used for server-side development, mobile applications, desktop applications, and game development. JavaScript is one of the most popular and widely used languages in the world.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container__subsect container__subsect-3" data-title="Endpoint management">
    <div class="subsect-text">
      Endpoint management is the process of securing and maintaining the devices that connect to a network, such as laptops, smartphones, tablets, and printers. Endpoint management involves installing software updates, enforcing security policies, detecting and resolving threats, and providing remote support.
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dg7h6aws/).

References:

- [`backdrop-filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter).
- [`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color).
- [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border).
- [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
- [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).
- [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis).
- [`flex-flow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).
- [`font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size).
- [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap).
- [`inset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inset).
- [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).
- [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).
- [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).
- [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).
- [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).
- [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align).
- [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition).

Comment: This solution is great. I learned a lot from you adding the class 'container__subsect' to the elements, then using absolute positioning, 0 inset, and hidden overflow. Also using the data attribute was next-level. I will read the docs and incorporate this into my JS/CSS in future. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes